# Suddenly my BackboneJS collections don't work in Chrome when the code is minified

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, collections

Suddenly my BackboneJS collections don't work in Chrome when the code is minified.
I have been searching for a bug in our code. But after fix some bugs, the application continue breaking when I use collections. If I change the collection for an array, the application works, but the next collection in the execution will cut again the execution.

I have to say that my application is really big. I have a model with lots of information and it has nested collections and models.

An example of a model with a collection, is usually the ones that fails.

```
    var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({ model: VinculacionesGrafo });

    var MyParentModel= Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: function () {
            return {
                mycollec: new MyCollection,
                finDeCarga: false
            };
        },

        initialize: function () {
            _.bindAll(this);
        },
        ....
        loadData: function () {
                var that = this;
                sendRequest({
                    type: "post",
                    url: ..,
                    dataType: "xml",
                    data: { ... },
                    success: this.success
                });
        },
        success: function(data) {
            model = new ChildModel;
            that.get("mycollec").add(model);
        }
```

It works allways in Firefox, Internet Explorer... But sometimes it fails in Chrome when the code is ready for production. I mean when the code is minified. At the beggining we thought it was a syncronoussly problem, but after change all collections by arrays it continues to fail in other collections that do not depends on loadding data. Allways the line with the error is something like:   that.get("mycollec").add(model); And the stack is the next:

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'operaciones' of null
     at h.extend.get 
     at h.extend.set 
     at h.extend.add
     at g.Model.extend.addItem 
     at f.extend.cargarNodosIniciales
```

And addItem method is the next (not related with the text error):

```
addItem: function (item) {
     this.get("nodos").add(item);
},
```

Allways the error is related with some data that it is null, but the stack is not related with the error text. When the code is obfuscate and we detected it the first time, the error was something like that:

> Cannot read property 1 of null.

The really strange thing is that when I change collections for arrays (in that code it will be mycollec: [] and push instead of add.) The bug does not appear anymore and the execution go on until it comes to another similar collection instruction.

I am really afraid. It is like backbone collections are broken. They works well sometimes and in the rest of the application they never fail. But It sames that section (that load lot of data and add lot of html) breaks backbone, or maybe is there a memory leak??

I am really lost. I am so sorry because the lack of the information the first time I wrote the question.

Thanks a lot in advance... I really need help

Comment: And what error you got?

Comment: I added it, so sorry I forgot that

Comment: do you have somewhere to put the minified version, so we can reproduce?

Comment: I think the minified version wouldn't be helpfull. I'm not sure if I can share the minified version. It's from the company. And you couldn't try the app because it will ask you for an user account. What more can I do for help?

Comment: Do you still think that the minified version will be helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have got the solution. @philfreo from github has answered my ticket in Backbone repository https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/issues/2701

It appears to happen only in versions 28 and 29 (beta) of chrome. In the 30 version  (canary) @philfreo said that it works.

He recommend us to do any of the next 3 options: 
+ Use unminified Backbonjs
+ Use Chrome 30 instead the previous versions
+ Apply a patch in Backbonejs code before minify https://github.com/elasticsales/backbone/commit/ba6e681cb898f2596899c8079d327cdd9c2f33fc

Another option would be to obfuscate the code and do not minify it. I took the minified and obfuscate code and make a prettify, after that I replaced the source code and it works. I'm not sure what are the options in google closure for make that. But it could be possible.

The patch works (third option)! So I wish help someone if he has this error. It is a really obscure bug and can take lot of time to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you defined the success function wrong. you just did **function success** and actually defining it globally instead of defining it in the Backbone.Model.extend argument

```
loadData:function(){...},
success:function(data){....},
```

Comment: I'm so sorry that is not the problem. I write it too fast. I was going to go out of the job in just that moment. I'm going to edit the question and I will add more details. I have several models with this kind of structure. Model with a this.get("collection"). Some have success inside the method, others had it outside. I edited it here and I forgot to move success outside. And all of that kind of models fails in some time of execution in Chrome. Only in Chrome and sometimes, so it is really hard to debug the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
success: this.success
```

When the success callback is triggered. It looks for the success event as a method on the **view**. But you have not defined it in the first place. You just created a function inside the scope of `localData` ..

It should have been this way  `success : success`

```
loadData: function () {
    var that = this;
    sendRequest({
        type: "post",
        url: ..,
        dataType: "xml",
        data: {...
        },
        success: this.success
    });

},
success: function (data) {
    model = new ChildModel;
    that.get("mycollec").add(model);
}
```

Now the method is available to the view. So `success : this.success` will work for this case.

Comment: I'm so sorry that is not the problem. I write it too fast. I was going to go out of the job in just that moment. I'm going to edit the question and I will add more details. I have several models with this kind of structure. Model with a this.get("collection"). Some have success inside the method, others had it outside. I edited it here and I forgot to move success outside. And all of that kind of models fails in some time of execution in Chrome. Only in Chrome and sometimes, so it is really hard to debug the problem.